# MYSQL - Only insert record if it does not already exist?

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I'm a noobie at mysql... but I'm trying to get this to check for a duplicate record based on the serialkey AND program. The record can only be submitted if the serialkey has not been submitted for that specific program already. 1 unique key is allowed PER program.

num is the unique number for each record

I had everything working properly with the record being submitted, BESIDES this duplicate check. Remember, I want the key to be allowed to be submitted multiple times, but ONLY once PER program.

```html
<?php
$title = "Product Key Submission";
$con=mysqli_connect("URL HERE","USER HIDDEN","PASS HIDDEN","DB");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$program = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['program']);
$key = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['serialkey']);
$time = time();
$registered = date('Y-m-d g:i:sa',$time);

if ($firstname == ""){
 echo "<h1>BLANK FIELD FOR NAME</h1>";
 mysqli_close($con);
}
else {
 //###################### CHECK IF RECORD EXISTS ######################
 $query = mysqli_query("SELECT count(*) AS 'num' FROM `product_keys` WHERE `program` = '$program' AND `serial_key` = '$key'");
 $num = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
 if ($num['num'] >= 1) {
  echo "You have reached your limit of key submissions.";
 }
 //###################### CHECK IF RECORD EXISTS ######################
 else {
   echo "THE KEY WILL BE SUBMITTED...";
```

Comment: Try `if ($num['num'] == 1)` or `if ($num['num'] >0)` - however, you'd probably be best to use `mysqli_num_rows()` - try it though.

Comment: Still no luck, it's still adding duplicate items when I try the '== 1' and '> 0'.

Comment: I think you can leave your code the way it is, you're not connecting with DB. Try `$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT...` - I've tested your code and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks man!!! That was the problem and everything is working properly! :D I was stuck on that forever since I'm new to all of this.

Comment: You're welcome. Would you like the question closed and I made it an answer? You can then accept it. It's your choice.

Comment: Yes, you can close it as your solution fixed it. Thanks again!

Comment: You're very much welcome. It has been posted below, *cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave your code the way it is, with the exception of:

Do:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT...
```

The problem is that you are not connecting with DB.

---

You may also have error reporting's default set to off.

It should have thrown the following warnings:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in...
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in...

Meaning that `mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters` is looking for a DB connection and the second warning message is because it enchains with the first warning and continues until it finds some form of success to stop the process.

which is why it was going to your

```
else {
        echo "THE KEY WILL BE SUBMITTED...";
```

condition.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`.